# What do the interconnection symbols mean on the MTR (subway) map in Hong Kong?

Tags: public-transport, hong-kong, maps

Looking at this [MTR (subway)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MTR) map in Hong Kong:

[image]

[source](https://thehkshopper.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/hong-kong-MTR-map.jpg)

I notice they used different interconnection symbols: [image]
[image]
[image][image]...

What do they mean?